# To find a part of text in column B from another A in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a combination of excel formulas , which can tell me if the string in Column A is present in column B or not.

In Column A i have values like:

```
335776
510770
514385
527400
411498
```

In Column B i have text like:

```
abc 411498 - Some random text
xx 411498 - Some random text 2
dfdag 335776 - Some random text 3
addf 510770 - Some random text
aff 514385 - Some random text 4
asded 514385 - Some random text 5
```

I would like to look to check if the values in Column A are present in Column B or not. If not present then that value be highlighted in RED (via conditional formatting). Thus following values in Column will be highlighted:

```
527400
```

I would not prefer to use macro, if a combination of INDEX, MATCH, FIND, etc. can work than that would be really great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This formula should help you:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,"*" & A1 & "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColumnA, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH("*"&A1&"*",B$1:B$6,0))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Font, Color: red, OK, OK, OK.